# jQuery autocomplete with multiple items not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-autocomplete

I am working on jQuery autocomplete which as two items in a `<ul>`.

I am getting json item from $.getJSON function and the json object looks like :

```
[{
     "merchant_name": "Myntra",
     "merchant_details": "Flat Rs.225 Cashback"
}, {
     "merchant_name": "Adlabs imagica",
     "merchant_details": "Rs 170 per sale"
}, {
     "merchant_name": "godaam",
     "merchant_details": "Rs 140 per sale"
}, {
     "merchant_name": "Homeshop18",
     "merchant_details": "Upto 8% Cashback"
}]
```

My function looks as follows:

```
$('#search_bar').keyup(function(e) {
    var searched = $('#search_bar').val()
    $.getJSON('<?php echo base_url();?>get_data', 'title=' + searched, function(result) {
        var elements = [];
        $.each(result, function(i, val) {
            elements.push({
                'merchant_name': val.merchant_name,
                'merchant_details': val.merchant_details
            })
        }) $('#search_bar').autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            source: elements,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $("input#search_bar").val(ui.item.merchant_name + " / " + ui.item.merchant_details);
                $("#get").click();
            }.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a><strong>" + item.merchant_name + "</strong> / " + item.merchant_details + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
            };
        })
    })
});
```

I am not able to proceed forward.

Please help me to solve this one.

Comment: Your function looks like it is doing a lot of things in once, perhaps abstract out a few things and get it working?  Your autocomplete will take care of the keypress event detection as well as seeking out responses from your server, if that is what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I need to get the json by using get method. So I am using keyup function. My actual doubt is with this line  $("input#search_bar").val(ui.item.merchant_name + " / " + ui.item.merchant_details); elements is set of objects. so i am not able to get ui.item.merchant_details. Is there any other way to do it

Comment: Why can you not let the autocomplete get information that will be displayed to the user?

Comment: Check out the official examples they should help you cover everything you need to do. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

Comment: Also if you are unsure if a variable is a set/object why not inspect it with the console? Use console.log( ui ); and view the results in firebug or any other web dev console

Comment: @HackerRocker Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this for one of my projects and it works perfectly. I'm not sure why you are detecting keyup when autocomplete does that for you... But this snippet should give you all the functionality you need.

```
$("#edit_profile .location").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: BASE_URL + "lib/ajax.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: "autocomplete_location=1&term=" + request.term,
                cache: false,
                success: function(resp) {
                    try {
                        json = $.parseJSON(resp);
                    } catch (error) {
                        json = null;
                    }
                    //
                    if (json && json.status == "OK") {
                        //
                        response($.map(json.predictions, function(item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.description,
                                value: item.description
                            }
                        }));
                        //
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (!ui.item){
                $(this).val("");
            }
        }
    });
```